# Lookup value between two dates from a separate table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables of the following format:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I want to lookup the "Date" from Table 1 against Table 2 and pull through the "Month" for which the "Date" lies between the "Start Date" and "End Date".

[image: Table 3]

I've considered expanding Table 2 to include all dates between the start date and end date. But there is no "DatesBetween" formula there is in DAX.

Comment: Did either of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, where Table2 is the Start/End date table and Table1 is the other table

in Table1, add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= (x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each x[Date]>=[Start Date] and x[Date]<=[End Date])[Month]{0}
```

sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Month",(x)=>Table.SelectRows(Table2, each x[Date]>=[Start Date] and x[Date]<=[End Date])[Month]{0})
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]